# Not able to create Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to create a simple docker swarm of two systems in my local network. I gave command `docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-ns78a9s9d9alnma7qnhwdna9o0hdf8ei8f xx.xx.xx.xx:2377` to make other system join the swarm. But I am getting error `Error response from daemon: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable`.
My systems are behind proxy and I have configured docker with proxy as well. I am able to download docker images and I can ping the other system as well.

Comment: Have you checked if you can connect your hosts through the required ports? (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts). You can use something like `nc` or `telnet` to test the communication between them. Also, it would be good if you improve your questions with more details. It's hard to help with limited information.

Comment: I used "curl -s xx.xx.xx.xx:2377 >/dev/null && echo Success. || echo Fail"  and it returned success. I tried from both systems and it returned success. So I guess connectivity is there.

Comment: Is it possible for you to try adding your machines to the `NO_PROXY` rule? (https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy) I think (but I'm not sure) that your proxy isn't letting your machines communicate correctly... Also, I would try using `nc` or `telnet` to test your connectivity, instead of using `curl`.

Comment: Adding to NO_PROXY rule worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I think it would be nice if you answer your own question, just explaining what you've done! :D

Comment: @user9040429 How did you fix this problem, could you answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Swarm nodes must have direct access to each other, and can't communitate through NAT or a proxy for intra-Swarm communcations.

Plus, you'll want to be sure they can talk to each other on the [proper Swarm ports](https://www.bretfisher.com/docker-swarm-firewall-ports/):

- TCP port 2377 for cluster management & raft sync communications
- TCP and UDP port 7946 for "control plane" gossip discovery communication
- UDP port 4789 for "data plane" VXLAN overlay network traffic

Comment: Thank for the answer, allowing those ports on firewall does works for me. These are the ports I allow on firewall: 2377/tcp, 2376/tcp, 7946/tcp, 7946/udp and 4789/udp.